# How to update table with sequentional on table without primary key?

Tags: sql, db2, db2-luw

In DB2 on Linux v11.1 I have a table:

```
COL1   COL2  "COLn 50 more columns"
A      A
A      A
B      A
B      B
etc 3 million rows
```

There can be multiple rows with the same rows, like first two rows in my sample (so obvious there is no primary key on table).

Now I have to add new column ID and set for every row unique sequential number.
The result should be:

```
COL1   COL2  "COLn 50 more columns"   ID
A      A                               1
A      A                               2
B      A                               3
B      B                               4
etc 3 million rows
```

How to write such an update statement to update ID column?
Regards

Comment: Does the sequence in the `ID` column depend on all 50 columns, only the first 2, or something else?

Comment: Every row should have its own ID number. The problem is two or more rows can have exactly the same data in all 50 columns.

Comment: *"...obvious there is no primary key on table"* That's not obvious at all. It just means that 'COL1, COL2' is not the primary key.

Comment: Lesson learned: _Always_ have a primary key in your table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it, using an `identity column` , and it assumes that there is not an existing Primary Key or identity column.

```
alter table myschema.mytab add column id integer not null default 0 ;

alter table myschema.mytab alter column id drop default ;


alter table myschema.mytab alter column id set generated always as identity ;


update myschema.mytab set id = default ;

-- optional, if you want the new ID column to be a surrogate primary key

alter table myschema.mytab add constraint pkey primary key(id) ;

reorg table myschema.mytab ;

runstats on table myschema.mytab with distribution and detailed indexes all;
```

Comment: Thanks this is even better then I expected. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
alter table myschema.mytab add column id integer not null default 0 ;

UPDATE (SELECT ID, ROWNUMBER() OVER() RN FROM myschema.mytab) SET ID = RN;
-- Or even simplier:
-- UPDATE myschema.mytab SET ID = ROWNUMBER() OVER();
```

Comment: First update works fine it sets sequential number. Second (commented) update does not work, it updates no row.

Comment: @folow Check the [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=15e5224604acfcd5c0933978f8be998b).